# Universality in terms of hom-sets

Tags: category-theory

I'm studying [this text](https://mroman42.github.io/ctlc/ctlc.pdf) which provides a shortcut in category theory for the notions I'm interestd in. Consider this theorem:

[image]

I understand the left to right implication. However, I'm not sure what is implied by the right to left implication.

To me it seems like they're taking any bijection between $hom(D_0,-)$ and $hom(C,G -)$ and proving it has to be of the form $G - \circ \; u$.

On the other hand there seems to be an abuse of notation as $u = \varphi(id_{D_0})$ seems to suggest that we can apply $\varphi$ to morphisms of $D$ while I would be expecting that only a particular $\varphi_D$ component of the natural isomorphism could be applied to it.

Could you please clarify what is implied by the theorem? A slow proof might enlighten this.

Comment: You're right, there is a slight abuse of notation in omitting the subscript on $\varphi$, but it's a common one in the literature when it's clear at which object the natural transformation is being applied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easier to use a commutative diagram, to see what is going on. Let's paste the one from Wiki and use it to prove the claim.

> Definition: the arrow $\phi$ as described below is universal if for any $Y\in D$ and $f: X \to U(Y)$, then there exists a unique morphism $g: A \to Y$ such that the following diagram commutes:

[image]

The definition implies that the function $\Phi:\hom[A,Y]\to \hom[X,U(Y)]:g\mapsto U(g)\circ \phi$ is a natural isomorphism, as you point out.

On the other hand, suppose there is a natural isomorphism $\Phi:\hom[A,Y]\to \hom[X,U(Y)]$. You want to prove that $\Phi(1_{A}):X\to U(A)$ is universal. So, let $Y\in D$ and $f: X \to U(Y)$, and define $g=\Phi^{-1}(f).$ Then, we get what we want because, using the naturality of $\Phi$ (where?), we have

$$U(g)\circ \Phi(1_A)=U(\Phi^{-1}(f))\circ \Phi(1_A)=\Phi(g)=\Phi\circ \Phi^{-1}(f)=f$$

Uniqueness of $g$ follows immediately because $\Phi$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: sorry for the silly question, but why is $\Phi(1_A)$ defined? I mean $\Phi$ should apply to elements of $hom[A,Y]$ and $1_A$ is in $hom[A,A]$?

Comment: You are $\textit{given},\ \Phi$. So, if you take $Y=A$  then $\Phi$ must send $1_A$ to an arrow in $\hom(X,U(A)).$ And you are claiming that this arrow is universal.

Comment: That is, $\Phi$ is natural in $Y$ so you can vary it. In other words, $\Phi$ is a natural transformation whose components are $\Phi_Y$. As pointed out in the other comment, one usually omits the subscript. it is understood.